# Django Project ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, django

I just ran a project and got the following error:

```
14:01:07 web.1  |   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
14:01:07 web.1  |     __import__(name)
14:01:07 web.1  | ImportError: No module named pinpoint.urls
```

and

```
14:01:07 web.1  |   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
14:01:07 web.1  |     __import__(name)
14:01:07 web.1  | ImportError: No module named pinpoint.apps.messagemanager
14:01:07 web.1  | Internal Server Error: /
```

And more like these.

I can't seem to understand why I am getting these import errors. There are more than just these, all the apps are getting import errors.  I am running a virtualenv and ran this for the first time after cloning it. The apps all seem to be installed properly:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'pinpoint.apps.careers',
    'pinpoint.apps.contact',
    #'south',
    'pinpoint.apps.beaconmanager',
    'pinpoint.apps.geofencemanager',
    'pinpoint.apps.locationmanager',
    'pinpoint.apps.messagemanager',
)
```

Edit: 
My file structure as requested: https://app.box.com/s/hhqv72jeqbv9yv41p71r

Edit again: python path-

```
>>> for path in sys.path:
...     print path
... 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Gimbpy-1.0-py2.7.egg
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-2.2.1-py2.7.egg
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
>>>
```

Comment: Can you post your project's directory structure and your python path?

Comment: Did you run `pip install -r requirements.txt` ? `INSTALLED_APPS` not install those apps, but simple say, which of installed apps this django app should use.

Comment: knbk, I have updated my question with the file structure, not sure how to show you my python path. noisy, I did run pip install -r requirements.txt.

Comment: I don't see pinpoint listed in your site-packages or your directory tree screenshot. Is pinpoint one of your apps? Is there a urls.py in pinpoint? Should pinpoint be dashboard?

Comment: You sir, are a genius. It was importing the wrong name and I completely looked over that fact. Thank you!